# TensorFlow 2.0 scatter add

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I would like to implement the following design in TensorFlow 2.0.

Given a `memory` tensor of shape `[a, b, c]`,
an `indices` tensor of shape `[a, 1]`,
and an `updates` tensor of shape `[a, c]`,

I want to increment `memory` at the positions indicated by `indices` with the values in `updates`.

`tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add` does not seem to work:

`tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add(memory, indices, updates)` returns `{InvalidArgumentError}Inner dimensions of output shape must match inner dimensions of updates shape. Output: [a,b,c] updates: [a,c] [Op:TensorScatterAdd]`.

Is it really necessary for `updates` to have as many inner dimensions as `memory` ? In my logic, `memory[indices]` (as a pseudocode) should already be a tensor of shape `[a, c]`. Furthermore, the shape of `tf.gather_nd(params=memory, indices=indices, batch_dims=1)` is already `[a, c]`.

Could you please recommend an alternative ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a, b, c = 3, 4, 5
memory = tf.ones([a, b, c])
indices = tf.constant([[2], [0], [3]])
updates = 10 * tf.reshape(tf.range(a * c, dtype=memory.dtype), [a, c])
print(updates.numpy())
# [[  0.  10.  20.  30.  40.]
#  [ 50.  60.  70.  80.  90.]
#  [100. 110. 120. 130. 140.]]

# Make indices for first dimension
ind_a = tf.range(tf.shape(indices, out_type=indices.dtype)[0])
# Make full indices
indices_2 = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(ind_a, 1), indices], axis=1)
# Scatter add
out = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add(memory, indices_2, updates)
print(out.numpy())
# [[[  1.   1.   1.   1.   1.]
#   [  1.   1.   1.   1.   1.]
#   [  1.  11.  21.  31.  41.]
#   [  1.   1.   1.   1.   1.]]
# 
#  [[ 51.  61.  71.  81.  91.]
#   [  1.   1.   1.   1.   1.]
#   [  1.   1.   1.   1.   1.]
#   [  1.   1.   1.   1.   1.]]
# 
#  [[  1.   1.   1.   1.   1.]
#   [  1.   1.   1.   1.   1.]
#   [  1.   1.   1.   1.   1.]
#   [101. 111. 121. 131. 141.]]]
```

Comment: Indeed, your code gives the desired behaviour. Can the `tensor_scatter_nd_add` operation update the `memory` tensor in-place ? My goal is to compute a differentiable loss function that depends on `memory`, do you know if this approach is problematic for calculating the gradients ?

Comment: @George Technically, there isn't such a thing as "in-place" in TensorFlow. Tensor are immutable, and only variables can see their value changed, `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add` gives you a new tensor that is the result of adding the values in `updates` to the positions in `indices`. This should back-propagate gradients correctly, both to `memory` and `updates`.